# Object not found - R

Tags: r, json

I am trying to construct data.tree from json/dataframe I have got.

```
library(data.tree)
construct_tree <- function(x) {

  gq <- Node$new("sessions")
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)) {
    if(x[i,c("type")] != 'RECORD')
       gbq$AddChild(x[i,c("name")])
    else
      y <- as.data.frame(x[i,c('fields')])
      print(y)
  }
 gq
}
```

This is how the data looks,

```
dput(data_samp)
structure(list(name = c("date", "totals"), type = c("STRING", 
"RECORD"), fields = list(NULL, structure(list(mode = c("NULLABLE", 
"NULLABLE", "NULLABLE", "NULLABLE", "NULLABLE", "NULLABLE", "NULLABLE", 
"NULLABLE", "NULLABLE", "NULLABLE", "NULLABLE", "NULLABLE", "NULLABLE"
), name = c("visits", "hits", "pageviews", "timeOnSite", "bounces", 
"transactions", "transactionRevenue", "newVisits", "screenviews", 
"uniqueScreenviews", "timeOnScreen", "totalTransactionRevenue", 
"sessionQualityDim"), type = c("INTEGER", "INTEGER", "INTEGER", 
"INTEGER", "INTEGER", "INTEGER", "INTEGER", "INTEGER", "INTEGER", 
"INTEGER", "INTEGER", "INTEGER", "INTEGER")), .Names = c("mode", 
"name", "type"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 13L)))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), .Names = c("name", "type", "fields"))
```

But in the else condition, when i try to use object 'y', i keep getting `Error in print(y) : object 'y' not found`

Can anyone advise what i am doing wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: sometimes when thecondition is met, nothing is assigned to `y` hence object `y` will not be found. maybe you should save something as y when the condition is met. In that case, y will be there whether the condition is met or not

Comment: But that triggers only when it goes to else condition right ?

Comment: then you should use the curly brackets:`else {….}` identation does not work in R. the curly braces will group the statements that should be manipulated under the else condition

Comment: @Onyambu's suggestion fixes it for me (plus fixing the `gbq` typo).

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes that works. Switching btw R & Python, always forget this small things. :(

Comment: @Onyambu Please add an answer, i can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra curly braces around the else condition statements:

```
library(data.tree)
construct_tree <- function(x) {

  gq <- Node$new("sessions")
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)) {
    if(x[i,c("type")] != 'RECORD')
       gbq$AddChild(x[i,c("name")])
    else{
      y <- as.data.frame(x[i,c('fields')])
      print(y)}
  }
 gq
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Instead of print(y), I am trying to do this - `parent <- x[i,"name"]
parent$AddChild(y[j,c("name")])`. I keep getting `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` . Any idea how i can approach this?

Comment: @ds_user parent is a vector and not a dataframe. ie x[I,"name"] is a single value. And you have stored that single value to parent. So you cannot use $ to access the single value in parent

Comment: Yeah, but as per this - `https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html` - creating programmatically, I am creating parent nodes first and adding child nodes on that. And I am trying to get the parent name from the data itself.

Comment: @ds_user. I am not quite familiar with data.tree. I would suggest that you ask that question